# Use of 'new' for arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I've been undertaking some basic tutorials. One of which has asked me to set up an array to hold the following string values:

```
Beyonce (f)
David Bowie (m)
Elvis Costello (m)
Madonna (f)
Elton John (m)
Charles Aznavour (m)
```

Write a program to loop round, count how many are male vocalists and how many are female, and display my answer in the console.

I managed to complete it, but the way I set up my array was different to the answer provided.

Mine is as follows:

```
String names[] = {"Beyonce (f)", "David Bowie (m)", "Elvis Costello (m)", "Madonna (f)", "Elton John (m)", "Charles Aznavour (m)"};
```

And the provided answer is as such:

```
String[] singers = new String[6];
singers[0] = "Beyonce (f)";
singers[1] = "David Bowie (m)";
singers[2] = "Elvis Costello (m)";
singers[3] = "Madonna (f)";
singers[4] = "Elton John (m)";
singers[5] = "Charles Aznavour (m)";
```

Should I be creating a "new" array? If so, why? And what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Basically there is no difference. one is shorthand the other is not. They are interchangable BUT the long version has the possebility to create an array that can contain more than 6 strings

Comment: I like your solution better although both are correct and produce the exact same result.

Comment: Apparently you knew things that you weren't supposed to know by that point, both are correct and the result will be the same :)

Comment: Both are correct, but @javapalava's answer is better than the official one. Well done!

Comment: Bringing my two cents to say that singers aren't String. You need a singer class with a name field and a gender field. Or you can call the array sSingers, with a hideous use of the hungarian notation ; see: good naming is also an important part of readability :))

Comment: How is this not a duplicate more than 6 years after Stack Overflow launched?

Comment: The compiler converts your answer into the provided answer automatically - it's only syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 35):

Your answer is equivalent but more readable and less error-prone because you don't need any "magic numbers" for each array element with the "fear" of accessing an element out of the array definition and therefore creating an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Also, a single array literal is easier to read than a list of assignments. Especially if you use some nice formatting to put each entry in the array on a new line. But the error-proneness of the official answer is the big one.

Answer (score 12):

Both are doing the same thing.

First approach is more dynamic. You are telling java compiler that those elements will create an array. Compiler knows in compilation time their length, so it creates an array to fit them all, secondly this is a single line declaration - so it takes less space and sets all values at once.

In your second attempt, you are first creating an array with length of 6. And then put in every slot one object.

First approach is better when:

- if you know from the start what elements will be in the array - it is cleaner, shorter
- it is also safer, because compiler created the array based on input length. Adding new element in code will change array size. In the second aproach you would have to change size manually, or ArrayOutOfBoundException will be thrown when adding singers[6].

Second approach is better wehen:

- But if there is some sort of logic that would determine order or values **in the runtime**.

But if you don't know the length of array, and you are expecting it to grow in the runtime, then you must use List or other dynamic structure (Set, List)

You can [find here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-java/).

Answer (score 6):

Both are valid ways to initialize an array.

Your way of initializing the array can only be done in the same expression that defines the array variable, though it can later be done in a similar way :

```
String[] names = null;
names = new String[] {"Beyonce (f)", "David Bowie (m)", "Elvis Costello (m)", "Madonna (f)", "Elton John (m)", "Charles Aznavour (m)"};
```

The provided answer explicitly creates an array of Strings, specifies the number of Strings that this array can store, and assigns values to the indices of the array.

Comment: I personally see this as bad coding style, because you create a state where your application has two different settings for the variable `names` depending on the state of the program - if a variable does not change (or ought to change) after the first assignment, I prefer final variables.

Comment: @Smutje I agree that if you know in advance what values are going to populate the array, there is no reason to separate the declaration from the initialization.

Comment: @Smutje I see the example more as an alternative syntax for the examples given by the OP. Upvoted you though for the "prefer final" comment ;)

Comment: At least you shouldn't initialize the array with `null` but simply declare it.  This way, the compiler will tell you if you attempt to use it before assigning a “good” value to it.

Answer (score 5):

Both solutions are correct. The first one uses an array initializer, the second one first instantiates the array and then populates it with values. One could argue that the first solution is more robust, since in the second solution the length of the array must be explicitly given before the entries are provided and it is possible to use indices beond the capacity of the array, which will be only detected at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

A new array can be created with the `new` operator followed by the array element type and the array size between the `[` `]` characters - this is called the [Array Creation Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10). Or when you declare a variable, you can also use an *array literal* which is called [Array Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) (but this cannot be used to assign a value to an array later on just when it is declared).

When you write

```
String names[] = {"A", "B", "C"};
```

It is just a short form and is equivalent to

```
String[] names = new String[] {"A", "B", "C"};
```

Note that to indicate that an array of the specified type is to be declared, both `String[] names` and `String names[]` forms can be used and they are equivalent, altough:

```
String names[], names2; // Only names is an array, names2 is just a String
```

While

```
String[] names, names2; // Both names and names2 are arrays!
```

It is recommended to use the second form to avoid confusion and accidents if later you add more variable names to the declaration.

### Let's take a closer look of what happens in the 2 cases:

```
// "Slow" filling
String[] names = new String[3]; // Filled with null values by default
names[0] = "A"; // Explicit index, index range check!
names[1] = "B"; // Explicit index, index range check!
names[2] = "C"; // Explicit index, index range check!

// "Fast" filling at creation time, implicit indices and array length,
// No index checks!
String[] names = {"A", "B", "C"};
```

### Advantages of creating and initializing the array in one step

There are several advantages of creating and initializing an array in one step:

- Doing so is less error-prone: the compiler will determine the length of the array, and also the compiler will initialize the elements of the array based on the list you provide. No such thing as using a wrong index value or getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
- It will be faster because the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) will not initialize the array with `null` values.
- It will be faster because you don't have to specify explicit index values and the JVM does not have to work with them. Also the JVM does not have to check if indices are in the valid range (that is `0..length-1`).
- Less maintenance/overhead when later you want to add another element in the middle of the array, you just have to insert it where you want it. Would you have initialized your array the other way, you would have to update all subsequent indices.
- The Java source code will be shorter, more compact and also the compiled byte code will be shorter.

You can read more about arrays in the [Java Language Specification: Chapter 10. Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html)

Comment: Your advantages are mostly wrong. Both/all forms allocate with `anewarray` which fills with nulls, and store each element with `aastore` 
which checks bounds. The only difference is "fast" form `dup`s ref on opstack while 
"slow" form `aload`s from local; if no more than 4 locals (including `this` for ctor or nonstatic method) this uses one-byte `aload_i` 
which is the same length, and both almost certainly hit L1 and are equally fast. Look with `javap`. Both can and probably will optimize when JITted. 
The *source* is indeed shorter, less error-prone, and easier to change.

Answer (score 0):

The 'new' operator in java is responsible for the creation of new object or we can say instance of a class.
Actually, it dynamically allocates memory in the heap with the reference we define pointed from the stack.

Comment: Just remember that `String names[] = {...};` simply is a shorthand notation for `String names[] = new String[]{...};` so there isn't any difference in the OP's example with regard to where the arrays live.

Comment: An array is not an instance of a class in Java.